# Azure AD authentication with auth code, only if third party cookie is enabled

Tags: cookies, azure-active-directory, cors

We are using Azure AD and have an application registered for authentication.  The application is a ASP.net server side and Angular client side application.  Initially this was setup with an implicit flow, but that rocked the web browsers cross site cookie protection.  The authentication worked, but only if the browser was explicitly allowing third-party cookies.

Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas) specifies that Single Page Applications can overcome this issue when using Authentication Code Flow.  To make this work we implemented `angular-auth-oidc-client` (instead of `msal-angular` which is yet to support auth code) with a configuration that is closely matching their provided [sample](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/tree/master/projects/sample-code-flow) program. The ASP.net application uses `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and its settings have been changed to have a `code` response type.

The Azure AD Application Registration was amended in line with the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code).  I have included a screenshot of the page highlighting the implicit flow is disabled and the SPA Redirect URI is eligible for Authorization Code Flow with PKCE.

However when blocking third party cookies in the browsers, the authentication fails basis the CORS policy (Safari, Chrome and both in private browsing).  When allowing third party cookies in the browsers the authentication is successful.

**Question** What could we investigate as the cause for not complying with the CORS policy?

[image: Azure AD application registration]

`Microsoft.Identity.Web` configuration:

```js
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "organizations",
        "ClientId": "removed_our_azure_ad_client_id",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
        "ResponseType": "code"
      },
```

Comment: I have created a guide (or a compilation of other guides) to show how to integrate the SPA with Web API on Azure AD with the correct settings for Authentication Code flow.

The guide is the readme, but I also have included a test project in the repository: https://github.com/superman-lopez/AzureAd_AspNet_Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the images you have shared the redirecturi `http://localhost:5000` is for SPA applications and `http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc` is for web application.

But In your configuration file `CallbackPath` is for web application.

Authorization Code Flow with PKCE is designed to work only for single page applications. Please go through [Prerequisites](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser#prerequisites)

Please use `CallbackPath` with URL given for SPA application to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I suspect I have a more fundamental problem with my configuration.  If I set the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` `CallbackPath` to be the SPA redirectUri, the middleware has no authentication (I get a `message.State is null or empty` error with `Unknown location`).  I'll first continue to try and make sense of all the sample projects.